# Range slider is glitching when it should stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rangeslider

The problem is that when it should stop by reaching certain value, it starts glitching (going back and forth really fast).

It does not glitch every time, it usually glitches 2 out of 3 times. After one time refresh because it will not work a second time.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Matc/pen/YxjMro)

```js
function number() {
  var xd = 20;
  var min = 0;
  var max = 100 - min;
  var mid = (100 - min) / 2 + min;
  var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + min);
  //document.getElementById("roll").value = x;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  var b = setInterval(function() {
    var newVal = $('#roll').val(function(i, val) {
      if (val > x) {
        return (+val - 0.1);
        clearInterval(b);
      } else {
        return (+val + 0.1);
        clearInterval(b);
      }
    });
  }, 1);
  if (x > mid) {
    console.log("high");
  } else {
    console.log("low");
  }
  console.log(x);
}

function random() {
  var counter = 6;
  var a = setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    if (counter >= 0) {
      span = document.getElementById("count");
      span.innerHTML = counter;
    }
    if (counter === 0) {
      clearInterval(a);
      span.innerHTML = '<h2>CountDown Complete!</h2>';
      number();
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
body {}

p {}

button {}

input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 500px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 500px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #ddd;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  height: 20px;
  min-width: 3px;
  max-width: 3px;
  width: 3px;
  background: #5CCA96;
  margin-top: -7px;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #ccc;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 500px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #ddd;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  border: none;
  height: 20px;
  width: 3px;
  background: #5CCA96;
}

input[type=range]:-moz-focusring {
  outline: 1px solid white;
  outline-offset: -1px;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 500px;
  height: 5px;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 6px 0;
  color: transparent;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #777;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  border: none;
  height: 20px;
  width: 3px;
  background: #5CCA96;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #888;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Random</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="random()">Try it</button>
  <div id="count"></div>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <input type="range" id="roll" name="slider" min="0" max="100" value="50" step="0.01" />

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `clearInterval(counter)`, but `counter` is not an interval, it's a number... Should be `var myInterval =  setInterval( ... )` and then `clearInterval(myInterval)`

Comment: Same with the other `clearInterval`. You need to pass it the return value of `setInterval`, which you currently ignore;

Comment: Besides, why do you include jQuery then use pure JS syntax like `document.getElementById().innerHTML` ? You should as well use jQuery.